# React Bootstrap Form.Check with Formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, formik

How can I properly bind `Form.Check` to a boolean variable using `yup` and `Formik`?

React-Bootstrap 4.5 provides an [example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-libraries) of using `Formik` + `yup` with form inputs. I was able to setup text inputs and selects, but encountered a problem with `Form.Check` element. I expect it to provide simple boolean value on change, but instead I'm getting an empty array `[]` or `["on"]` when checkbox is checked.

The documentation also has this issue, in the example from the link above form displays this error message:

`terms must be a boolean type, but the final value was: ["on"].`

[image]

My code:

```
const schema = yup.object({
    deactivated: yup.boolean(),
});

const initialValues = {
    deactivated: false,
};

return (
    <Formik
        validationSchema={schema}
        onSubmit={(
            values
        ) => {
            save(
                values.deactivated,
            );
        }}
        initialValues={initialValues}>
        {({
            handleSubmit,
            handleChange,
            values,
            errors,
        }) => (
            <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group controlId="deactivated">
                    <Form.Check
                        label="Deactivated"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value={values.deactivated}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        isInvalid={!!errors.deactivated}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
            </Form>
        )}
    </Formik>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to handle checkbox changes manually using `setFieldValue` method:

- extract `setFieldValue` method from Formik
- bind checkbox to `checked` property instead of `value`
- use custom `onChange` handler: `{e => setFieldValue('deactivated', e.target.checked)}`

Code:

```
return (
    <Formik
        validationSchema={schema}
        onSubmit={(
            values
        ) => {
            save(
                values.deactivated,
            );
        }}
        initialValues={initialValues}>
        {({
            handleSubmit,
            handleChange,
            values,
            errors,
            setFieldValue,
        }) => (
            <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group controlId="deactivated">
                    <Form.Check
                        label="Deactivated"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={values.deactivated}
                        onChange={e => setFieldValue('deactivated', e.target.checked)}
                        isInvalid={!!errors.deactivated}
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <<Button type="submit">Save</Button>
            </Form>
        )}
    </Formik>
);
```